# How to hide a drop down option based on the selection of another drop down in a form in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

*This is the JS code i used to hide option Delhi from Dropdown Destination when the option Delhi is chosen from Source*

```
   < script type = 'text/javascript' >
      function getSelectValue(Source) {
        if (Source != '') {
          $(Destination option[value = '"+Source+"']).hide();
        }

      } <
      /script>
```

This is the HTML code i'm using for the dropdown

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <!-- Source -->
                        <h5 class="card-title">Source</h5>
                        <select name="Source" id="Source" required="required" onchange= "getSelectValue(this.value);">
                            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                            <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                            <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                            <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Destination</h5>
                        <!-- Destination -->
                        <select name="Destination" id="Destination" required="required">
                            <option value="Cochin">Cochin</option>
                            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                            <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                            <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PS i have used it inside a form

Comment: Just to confirm are the options values are coming from a list or they are hard-coded in your project as well? What I want to know is are the options values are fixed or they are dynamic and you are showing them using a for loop?

Comment: Hi @Anna they are hardcoded into the project just the values mentioned in the above HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution as below

1. wrap your select inside a span with id
2. if selecting source push all your destination options to an array.
3. using span id find the option inside destination span by passing the selected source value.
4. while iterating on the options values don't forget to show all the values by passing the particular options values... if you skip this step the option you will hide in the first place won't be visible in the next step, ex. if you select Delhi for the first time delhi will be hidden from the destination using 5th step but now if you select Kolkata from the source again then kolkata will be hidden along with delhi from destination... just to avoid this first show all the options iterating over all the options and then hide the required one will do the work.
5. once found the matching destination with selected source hide it.
6. do vice versa for the source I have added a new function below.

```js
function getSelectValue(Source) {
  var optionsArr = [];
  var x = document.getElementById("Destination");
    var txt = "All options: ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      optionsArr.push(x.options[i].text);
      const options = $("#dest_span>select>option[value='"+x.options[i].text+"']").show();
    }
    const options = $("#dest_span>select>option[value='"+Source+"']").hide();
}
function getSelectValueDest(Dest) {
  var optionsArr = [];
  var x = document.getElementById("Source");
    var txt = "All options: ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      optionsArr.push(x.options[i].text);
      const options = $("#src_span>select>option[value='"+x.options[i].text+"']").show();
    }
    const options = $("#src_span>select>option[value='"+Dest+"']").hide();
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- Source -->
            <h5 class="card-title">Source</h5>
            <span id="src_span">
            <select
              name="Source"
              id="Source"
              required="required"
              onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)"
            >
              <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
              <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
              <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
              <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Destination</h5>
            <!-- Destination -->
            <span id="dest_span">
            <select name="Destination" id="Destination" required="required" onchange="getSelectValueDest(this.value)">
              <option value="Cochin">Cochin</option>
              <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
              <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
              <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
            </select>
            <span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Adding code snippet for reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- Source -->
            <h5 class="card-title">Source</h5>
            <select
              name="Source"
              id="Source"
              required="required"
              onchange="getSelectValue(this)"
            >
              <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
              <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
              <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
              <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Destination</h5>
            <!-- Destination -->
            <select name="Destination" id="Destination" required="required">
              <option value="Cochin" >Cochin</option>
              <option value="Delhi" id="Delhi">Delhi</option>
              <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
              <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function getSelectValue(elem) {
      const value = elem.value;
      if (value === "Kolkata") {
        document.getElementById("Delhi").remove();
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed my initial answer, where I misunderstood your question(this is final version), so basically if you select Kolkata for example it will remove Delhi from the second dropdown.
And you can adjust code for you needs

Comment: Sorry forgot to add I'd for Delhi

Comment: So as per your solution if i change the value to Delhi will the desired result be produced

Comment: My solution is not dynamic because you didn't specify what is your further requirements.
This code needs to be adjusted accordingly if you want Delhi to hide Cochin for example.
Can you accept my answer as working one? =)

Comment: My problem is as there are 2 options with the name delhi 1 in Source and 1 in Destination. So if i select the option Delhi in Source the option in Destination is to be either hidden or disabled and vice versa

Comment: I hope it gives a clarity for the requirement